# How to display a total of time values?

Tags: crystal-reports

Using Crystal Report 8.5

In Crystal report time column values are String. I display a record order by person id.

Like this.

Personid Intime Outtime

```
001 08:00:00 17:00:00
001 14:00:00 22:00:00
002 07:00:00 10:00:00
002 04:00:00 21:00:00
```

...,

From the above report i need a total of Intime, total of Outtime group by personid

Expected Outtput

```
Personid Intime Outtime

001   08:00:00 17:00:00
001   14:00:00 22:00:00
Total 22:00:00 39:00:00

002   07:00:00 10:00:30
002   04:00:00 21:00:30
Total 11:00:00 31:01:00
```

...,

I will display all the value along with total by personid wise.

Need Crystal Report Formula Help.

Comment: What good is that total? Are you sure you don't want the total of (Outtime - Intime)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert your times to seconds and then get your total.  In your display format the seconds as hours, minutes seconds.
For the Intime field, in the Crystal Report, create a formula in your details section:

```
@IntimeSeconds  
ToNumber(Left({table.Intime}, 2) * 3600) + ToNumber(Mid({table.Intime}, 4, 2) * 60) + ToNumber(Mid({table.Intime}, 7, 2))
```

You can now place a formula in the group footer to display the total Intime seconds as hh:mm:ss

```
@ShowTotalIntime  
Numbervar TotalTime := Count({table.Intime}, {table.Group});
Numbervar IntimeHours := TotalTime\3600;  
NumberVar IntimeMinutes := (TotalTime%3600)\60;  
Numbervar IntimeSeconds := (TotalTime%60);  
ToText(IntimeHours, "00") + ":" + ToText(IntimeMinutes, "00") + ":" ToText(IntimeSeconds, "00");
```

Do a similar thing for Outtime.

Comment: I Create a Formula in Field Explorer - Formula Fields, It Showing Error as "Remaining Text does not appear in the formula"

Comment: For the First Formula, Showing Error as A Number, or Currency amount is required here.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at my ElapsedTime() function.  http://www.cogniza.com/blog/?p=31